# How can accomplish a dual div swap on rollover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I am looking for advice on a way to accomplish this. Given the following:

[Div A (contains an image)]
[Div B (contains a horizontal list of 8 or so text links)]
[Div C (contains text)]

Upon rolling over any link in Div B, how can I have Div A and Div C swap their respective contents out to something different that corresponds to the content of that link?

For example, if one were to rollover a Div B link called "Dogs", then upon that rollover, Div A would replace its contents and display an image of a dog and Div C would replace its contents and display text about dogs.

After rolling over that link, the new Div A and Div C contents will remain in place until a new link is rolled over.

I hope this makes sense. Does anyone have advice on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Where do the contents of div A and C come from? That is - how do you decide what to put into them?

Comment: The contents of Div A and Div C are purely based on which link was last rolled over. Since the first Div B link might be "Dogs", then Div A would be initialized to contain an image of a dog and Div C would be initialized to contain text about dogs. However, if the Div B link "Cats" were rolled over, then Div A would hide/remove the image of a dog and instead display an image of a cat, and Div C would hide/remove the text about dogs and instead display text about cats... until yet another link was rolled over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... this should be pretty simple with jQuery (compared to some of the other answers here):

If you're unfamiliar with jQuery, the $() is a shortcut for calling jQuery(), and using

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```

is a way to make sure jQuery fires at the right time. Read more about that [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready).

So first, add a class (ie .dogs) to each `<a>` element in your #divB list. Next, give each of the corresponding images the same class, and contain each of your text blocks in #divC in divs with the same class as well. The HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="divA">
   <img src="dogs.jpg" class="dogs" />
   <img src="flowers.jpg" class="flowers" />
   <img src="cars.jpg" class="cars" />
</div>
<div id="divB">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="dogs.html" class="dogs">Dogs</a></li>
      <li><a href="flowers.html" class="flowers">Flowers</a></li>
      <li><a href="cars.html" class="cars">Cars</a></li>
   </ul
</div>
<div id="divC">
   <div class="dogs"><p>Text about dogs.</p></div>
   <div class="flowers"><p>Text about flowers.</p></div>
   <div class="cars"><p>Text about cars.</p></div>
</div>
```

Then use the following jQuery, putting this up in the `<head>` section of your HTML doc:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('a.dogs').hover(function() {
        $('#divA img').hide("fast");
        $('#divA img.dogs').show("fast");
        $('#divC div').hide("fast");
        $('div.dogs').show("fast");
     });
 });
```

We say when the document is ready, when you hover over the `<a>` element with the .dogs class, perform a function. That function will hide all of the images in #divA and immediately show the image with the .dogs class. Then it will hide all of the divs in the #divC and immediately show the div with the .dogs class.

You can do the same thing twice more for .flowers and .cars, or however many you have.

Keep in mind, there are more efficient ways of doing this too, if you're interested in looking deeper into jQuery, but this will be a solid way to get started in helping you understand exactly what jQuery is doing. And it keeps the script OUT of the HTML body, too!

Comment: Oh and don't forget to enclose the above jQuery in <script></script> tags.

Comment: Thanks, this seems pretty clear! I'm definitely a jQuery newbie, so I'm going to give this a try as it makes sense to me. Once I get the basics down I'll look into more efficient ways of doing this... Thanks again to everybody!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `href` points to one resource that contains the content for both, but you can't just inject the entire output of the link into one element, something like this could work:

```
$('#divB a').mouseover(function() {

    //get images from link, inject into divA
    $('#divA').html('<strong>Loading...</strong>')
              .load($(this).attr('href') + ' img');

    //get divs from link, inject into divC
    $('#divC').html('<strong>Loading...</strong>')
              .load($(this).attr('href') + ' div'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change a div's contents with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function over() {
        var a = document.getElementById('a');
        var c = document.getElementById('c');

        a.style.backgroundImage = "url(/path/to/image)";
        c.innerHTML = "<b>Dogs rock</b>";
    }
</script>

<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b" onmouseover="over();"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Then all you need to do is add whatever other div's you want and write code to change them appropriately. Set the initial state of A and C using css, or just call the over() function on page load.